# Azure SQL Edge Does not persist data to docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-sql-database

I'm having troubles persisting database data to docker volume.

I have a docker compose with azure SQL edge container. Here is the configuration for the container:

```
services:
  azure-sql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge"
    hostname: "azure-sql"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 1
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: ":8jNZdK7cK"
      MSSQL_USER: "SA"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    volumes:
      - azure-sql-storage:/var/opt/mssql-extensibility/data
      - azure-sql-storage:/var/opt/mssql-extensibility/log
      - azure-sql-storage:/var/opt/mssql-extensibility
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"

volumes:
  azure-sql-storage:
    external: true
```

I noticed that each time azure SQL re-runs a container it creates new folders in the mapped volumes instead of using the old ones and stores data there.

[image]

Is there any chance I can persist data and reuse it even when containers are disposed? May Azure SQL container can be configured so reuse previously created directories instead of creating new?

I tested stand alone container but the result was the same.

Also I noticed that if I stop containers instead of disposing them and re-run them – data is persisted.

**UPD**

Looks like it's a known issue. It's mention on the dockerhub page:
"Mounting a volume does not work on Docker for Mac"

Comment: I am facing this issue, if you check out the known issues https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge says that "Mounting a volume does not work on Docker for Mac". If you have resolved the issue please add it as answer. thanks

Comment: @navdbaloch unfortunately, I have not been able to fix this issue yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how old that known-issue about using volumes on a Mac is, but I was able to.

```
volumes:
  - azure-sql-storage:/var/opt/mssql
```

Got it from [here](https://github.com/mafudge/learn-databases/blob/e96cc01b759c465f7794e2e2b1b048ef987ff3d0/docker-compose-azure-sql.yaml#L14).

Comment: Hi @eShinn

I can see that this is still an issue at the [official azure SQL image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge). Did you try it locally on your machine?